# What's the best way to aggregate the boolean values of a Python dictionary?

Tags: python

For the following Python dictionary:

```
dict = {
    'stackoverflow': True,
    'superuser': False,
    'serverfault': False,
    'meta': True,
}
```

I want to aggregate the boolean values above into the following boolean expression:

```
dict['stackoverflow'] and dict['superuser'] and dict['serverfault'] and dict['meta']
```

The above should return me `False`.  I'm using keys with known names above but I want it to work so that there can be a large number of unknown key names.

Comment: An *infinite* number of keys?!

Comment: @Mark Byers: He doesn't know how many keys will be in the dict or what they will be, why is this hard to comprehend?

Comment: @manifest: OK, then his question was wrong, so I've edited it to correct it. This is a Wiki and publicly viewable. The correct question is as important as the correct answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

in python 2.5+:

```
all(dict.itervalues())
```

in python 3+

```
all(dict.values())
```

`dict` is a bad variable name, though, because it is the name of a builtin type

Edit: add syntax for python 3 version. `values()` constructs a view in python 3, unlike 2.x where it builds the list in memory.